# Information on current GPU Architectures

Tags: architecture, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia, amd-gpu

I have decided that my bachelors thesis will be about general purpose GPU-computing and which problems are more suitable for this than others. I am also trying to find out if there are any major differences between the current GPU architectures that may affect this.

I am currently looking for some **scientific papers and/or information directly from the manufacturers about the current GPU Architectures**, but I can't seem to find anything that looks detailed enough. Therefore, I am hoping that someone may be able to suggest some papers or at least point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: I am very surprised that your search didn't turn up [this paper](http://www.stuffedcow.net/research/cudabmk), which is just about the last word on 3rd party analysis of a modern DX10/DX11 GPU architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read litterature about OpenCL and Cuda. Perhaps [OpenGPU](http://opengpu.net/) project site might give more links.

<sub>GPU manufacturers usually don't want to give detailed information. ATI seems to tell more than Nvidia. Some of ATI GPU chips have published VLIW instruction sets.</sub>

The trend is to give (e.g. in OpenCL runtime) several functions to query the hardware, and then enable you to tune your (OpenCL) application to what the hardware wants.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems helpful as well :)

Answer (score 1):

This paper from NVIDIA provides some details on their Tesla architecture:

- [NVIDIA Tesla: A Unified Graphics and Computing Architecture](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MM.2008.31)

Of course, Tesla is one generation old at this point; I have not seen a peer-reviewed publication describing Fermi, NVIDIA's latest architecture. The best information from NVIDIA on Fermi may be in this white paper:

- [NVIDIA’s Next Generation CUDA Compute Architecture: Fermi](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/fermi_white_papers/NVIDIA_Fermi_Compute_Architecture_Whitepaper.pdf)

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of similar papers from AMD/ATI. I have seen a few third party papers that do provide some information; for example:

- [A Micro-benchmark Suite for AMD GPUs](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICPPW.2010.59)

One of the best third party sources of architecture information, in my opinion, is Real World Technologies. Here are some relevant articles from RWT:

- [AMD's Cayman GPU Architecture](http://realworldtech.com/page.cfm?ArticleID=RWT121410213827)
- [AMD Fusion Architecture and Llano](http://realworldtech.com/page.cfm?ArticleID=RWT062711124854)
- [Inside Fermi: Nvidia's HPC Push](http://realworldtech.com/page.cfm?ArticleID=RWT093009110932)
- [NVIDIA's GT200: Inside a Parallel Processor](http://realworldtech.com/page.cfm?ArticleID=RWT090808195242)