# How to run bullet physics solution on GPU

Tags: c++, gpu, bulletphysics

currently bullet physics solution runs on CPU.In this case,collision is very slow.I want to make the collision  faster.This can be achieved only by running the
solution on GPU.

Comment: What efforts have you done to optimize the collision detection?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to optimize your code and improve your algorithms. Perhaps consider some [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)...

<sup>(studying the underlying mathematics is definitely going to be useful; you might make a PhD on your topic)</sup>

Learn [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) and code your physics code with it (it would take you several weeks, and is platform specific). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9248755/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33195125/841108). Consider also multi-threaded (e.g. [POSIX threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) or C++11 [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)) and [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) approaches.

Comment: I would also consider first if the original code is decently optimized in first place before drawing the "big guns"...